# Pubnub publish not publishing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, pubnub

I am trying to publish a message to pubnub channel but its not publishing on server. However its working absolutely fine on local machine. Any idea where I am doing it wrong?

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :send_message_to_driver

  def send_message_to_ABC
    $pubnub.publish(
        channel: "chat_ABC",
        message: message
    ) do |env|
      puts env.parsed_response
    end
  end
end
```

$pubnub is being initialized globally for app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay with some research and debugging I am able to fix this issue. This issue was occurring because, by default, Ruby operations are asynchronous. So script is terminated before publish is complete. Luckily we have an option **http_sync** for this pubnub's publish method. Setting it to true makes sure that that flow is not terminated before publish is completed. So new code is

```
$pubnub.publish(
  http_sync: true,
  channel: "chat_ABC",
  message: message
) do |env|
  puts env.parsed_response
end
```